# How to set box version in puphpet's config.yaml?

Tags: version, yaml, config, box, puphpet

I am having an issue setting the vagrant box version to a particular one (not the latest) in the puphpet's **config.yaml**. I've tried with **box_version: 2.0** (educated guess, because i did not find any better solution) and running vagrant up still tries to get the lates version.

This is how the relevant portion of the config.yaml looks:

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        box: puphpet/centos65-x64
        box_url: puphpet/centos65-x64
        box_version: 2.0
```

And as you can see on vagrant up it still tries to fetch **>=0**:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...                                     
==> default: Box 'puphpet/centos65-x64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...   
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox                                                           
    default: Box Version: >= 0                                                                  
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'puphpet/centos65-x64'                                    
    default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puphpet/centos65-x64
```

I would appriciete some direction on this metter, what is the way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the box manually:

```
vagrant box add puphpet/centos65-x64 http://box.puphpet.com/centos-6.8-x86_64-20151130-virtualbox.box
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using box_version: '2'. Set the value as a sting.
Worked for me using puphpet/ubuntu1204-x64 and getting version 2.0

Cheers